# Help! How to remove a browser hijacker?

Tags: firefox, uninstall, security, browser, malware

All of a sudden this has shown up on my computer when I click on the + for a new tab:

```
search.newtabtvsearch.com/?src=ff_NewtabTV
```

I have found instructions on how to get it off Windows, but what about Ubuntu?

I am not a technical user, but can follow basic instructions. I have searched in my home folder and in my system folder but can't find this file. I need help - this thing is a nuisance at best and possibly destructive.

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: You might also want to scan your system with the `clamav` anti-virus.

Comment: I'm using Firefox.  How does one get to the clamov program?

Comment: @ccannon close Firefox, open a terminal then run : `cd ~; mv .mozilla .mozilla-bk`; reopen firefox see if your problem is solved.

Comment: You can install it with `sudo apt-get install clamav` in Terminal (CTRL+ALT+T). After you have installed it make sure to run `sudo freshclam` in order to update the AV virus signature database.

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure how to do that. Where do I find : mv .mozilla .mozilla-bk I'm really a basic user.

Comment: @ccannon - No, no, you just run that command in the terminal

Comment: @ccannon press ctrl+alt+t, a terminal will pops up. then enter this command: `cd ~; mv .mozilla .mozilla-bk` and hit the enter.

Comment: Ok, I will have to close FFox (& you guys - gulp) to do this. I"ve copied the command. I will press control+alt+t and then paste that in.....right?

Comment: Once you've installed ClamAV, run the following in Terminal: `sudo clamscan --detect-pua -i / | tea ~/ClamAVScan1.log`, then when it has finished running and you see a line returned to you with the `$` on it again as well as seeing the output of the scan you will have a log file called `ClamAVScan1.log` in your home directory. That should tell you about potentially infected and infected files which you could then remove. But probably best to check with us here first.

Comment: It's always good to have an AV installed, though `clamav` doesn't find rootkits so for that you need a clean install and `rkhunter` to be setup properly. But obviously you should probably try what the others are suggesting first.

Comment: I'm printing this out just in case :-0

Comment: Well, I found the Terminal and entered the code but nothing was ever "run".  I went back to Firefox and the "newtabtv" crap is gone, but so are all my bookmarks... hmmm. I do have them on Chromium so not a total loss. Very perplexing. Thanks for your help. Sorry I'm so basic... not a coder, just a user.

Comment: @ccannon  It ran. It worked. You owe them thanks. Now follow the rest of their excellent advice and install ClamAV. That's the path to getting your bookmarks back.

Comment: @user535733 ClamAV won't restore the bookmarks. OP needs to restore their Firefox profile for that. See my answer.

Comment: @wjandrea, yes - that's what a path toward a goal is. Nice answer, well-written.

Answer (score 1):

To start, try refreshing Firefox. If the issue returns, we will know there is more work to be done, although it would be best to do an antivirus scan preemptively.

Before doing this, you'll need to restore your `.mozilla` folder (which contains your Firefox profile) from backup, based on the comments on your question. Run this command in terminal:

```
mv ~/.mozilla-bk ~/.mozilla
```

Then refresh Firefox. Instructions from [Firefox help - Refresh Firefox](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/refresh-firefox-reset-add-ons-and-settings):

> 1. Click the menu button and then click help.
> 2. From the **Help** menu choose **Troubleshooting Information**.
>
>    - If you're unable to access the **Help** menu, type `about:support` in your address bar to bring up the **Troubleshooting Information** page.
> 3. Click the **Refresh Firefox** button in the upper-right corner of the Troubleshooting Information page.
> 4. To continue, click **Refresh Firefox** in the confirmation window that opens.
> 5. Firefox will close to refresh itself. When finished, a window will list your imported information. Click **Finish** and Firefox will open.

There is more info on the Firefox help page, including screenshots, what the refresh actually does, and where it backs up your existing data.

Comment: Thanks to all, as I said...  I was grateful anybody was hearing what was going on with me & taking the time to respond & educate me.. I refreshed Firefox, but bookmarks never came back. I have most of the ones I want in Chromium - am seeing this as a spring-clean decluttering moment instead of a loss. The next time "my computer guy" is here I will run this by him as well.

Comment: How to work this out in Google Chrome?

Comment: @Quark Chrome has a "Reset" feature similar to Firefox's refresh but a bit less destructive.